# NodeJS and Threads in 2015

Tags: node.js

I want to have a while(1) forever loop to communicate with devices [TCP] in parallel. Idea is to start threads for each IP Address [TCP Connection] and have them communicate forever. Currently number of devices i have to support is 200+
Questions are

1. NodeJS how to implement the while(1) strategy and as its event based how to gauge the timeout and response timings.
2. NodeJS will be able to handle 200+ threads? i have done this before in Windows application and it worked properly i'm having a server class machine [16 cores]
3. Any best practices suggested
4. Should i just keep the NodeJS to handle web traffic and move the communication server [TCP and Thread] code to in some navtive language?

Comment: Threads and `while(true)`loops are very rarely the answer in node.js. Node.js does is not designed to handle concurrent connections through threading, it does it through asynchronous event based operation.

It is usually able to handle several thousand concurrent connections on a single core (http://www.infoq.com/interviews/node-ryan-dahl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. take a look here - https://github.com/caolan/async#forever, probably the `until`,`doUntil` and `forever` are what you are looking
2. Yes, you can use [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) cluster to scale for 16 processes (one for each CPU core)
3. Use callbacks and Caolan Async, do not write synchronous code
4. Hard question, probably the Go language [light weight threads](https://golang.org/doc/faq#goroutines) are good for this task - see also [Go memory consumption with many goroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326765/go-memory-consumption-with-many-goroutines)

Answer (score 2):

If you think a `while` loop is the key here you're *seriously* misunderstanding the Node.js event-loop model. That's completely irrelevant. There's already a powerful event dispatch system built-in, there's no need to build your own on top of that.

Can Node.js handle threads? Sort of. Not really. If you have CPU intensive tasks that demand threading you should look at [webworkers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads), but the multi-process model is the one traditionally promoted by Node.

Remember: Node is all about **non-blocking asynchronous operations**, so threads are not going to help you there. This is not like Java where you'll have thousands of threads where they're making blocking calls. You do not create threads to handle each connection, you just write asynchronous code to handle them all on the same thread.

You should try and modularize your solution. Anything heavy should be wrapped up in to tasks that can be dispatched with an event bus like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) so you can manage the workflow.